# how to decipher a bundle from juju

Tags: juju

how do i decipher a juju bundle? For example its a wiki bundle with instances, etc and mysql configuration with memcache. The charms deploy no relationships are established or none of the services exposed.

How does a person go and read the yaml file so that the deployment bundle can be done by hand with the correct relationships etc?

In this example below, some of this I can figure out. The question is, where did amqp come from? In the first section I can see which charms need to be deployed and understand where they will appear on the canvas.

In the relations section i can see where there is a relationship for keystone and mysql. I do ok until i see

"mysql:shared-db"
    - - "nova-cloud-controller:amqp"
    - "rabbitmq-server:amqp"

What does this amqp mean? I have seen it deploy on the public facing juju charms site and for the life of me it wont deploy locally. Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

```
openstack:
services:
mysql:
charm: "cs:precise/mysql-27"
num_units: 1
annotations:
"gui-x": "572"
"gui-y": "428"
"rabbitmq-server":
charm: "cs:precise/rabbitmq-server-14"
num_units: 1
annotations:
"gui-x": "300.2281494140625"
"gui-y": "601.203857421875"
keystone:
charm: "cs:precise/keystone-21"
num_units: 1
annotations:
"gui-x": "1250"
"gui-y": "-582.5"
"nova-compute":
charm: "cs:precise/nova-compute-15"
num_units: 1
options:
"openstack-origin": "cloud:precise-grizzly"
annotations:
"gui-x": "1724.643310546875"
"gui-y": "710"
"nova-cloud-controller":
charm: "cs:precise/nova-cloud-controller-17"
num_units: 1
options:
"network-manager": Quantum
"openstack-origin": "cloud:precise-grizzly"
annotations:
"gui-x": "199.90336276669336"
"gui-y": "-472.5381696646418"
glance:
charm: "cs:precise/glance-22"
num_units: 1
options:
"openstack-origin": "cloud:precise-grizzly"
annotations:
"gui-x": "2012.591386603307"
"gui-y": "-193.16855882682512"
cinder:
charm: "cs:precise/cinder-12"
num_units: 1
options:
"openstack-origin": "cloud:precise-grizzly"
annotations:
"gui-x": "1184.4137742986195"
"gui-y": "937.8314411731749"
"quantum-gateway":
charm: "cs:precise/quantum-gateway-9"
num_units: 1
options:
"openstack-origin": "cloud:precise-grizzly"
annotations:
"gui-x": "2011.4137742986195"
"gui-y": "440.0091755481749"
"openstack-dashboard":
charm: "cs:precise/openstack-dashboard-11"
num_units: 1
annotations:
"gui-x": "1890.413896368932"
"gui-y": "-576.9908244518251"
relations:
- - "keystone:shared-db"
- "mysql:shared-db"
- - "nova-cloud-controller:cloud-compute"
- "nova-compute:cloud-compute"
- - "nova-cloud-controller:shared-db"
- "mysql:shared-db"
- - "nova-cloud-controller:amqp"
- "rabbitmq-server:amqp"
- - "nova-cloud-controller:identity-service"
- "keystone:identity-service"
- - "nova-compute:amqp"
- "rabbitmq-server:amqp"
- - "nova-compute:shared-db"
- "mysql:shared-db"
- - "nova-cloud-controller:image-service"
- "glance:image-service"
- - "nova-compute:image-service"
- "glance:image-service"
- - "glance:identity-service"
- "keystone:identity-service"
- - "glance:shared-db"
- "mysql:shared-db"
- - "nova-cloud-controller:cinder-volume-service"
- "cinder:cinder-volume-service"
- - "cinder:amqp"
- "rabbitmq-server:amqp"
- - "cinder:shared-db"
- "mysql:shared-db"
- - "cinder:identity-service"
- "keystone:identity-service"
- - "nova-cloud-controller:quantum-network-service"
- "quantum-gateway:quantum-network-service"
- - "quantum-gateway:amqp"
- "rabbitmq-server:amqp"
- - "quantum-gateway:shared-db"
- "mysql:shared-db"
- - "openstack-dashboard:identity-service"
- "keystone:identity-service"
```

Comment: Hi John, your last few questions seem to be hitting the bleeding edge of Juju bundle development, since the feature is in beta I'd like to just link up with you directly and connect you with the core devs. We're keen on getting you spun up and we can probably do it much quicker directly. Contact info is in my profile (click on my name) - after that we can document the procedures here for the benefit of everyone, hope to hear from you!

Comment: I did send a email, haven't heard back.

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck deciphering a simpler charm than the openstack one :)

- http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jorge/charms/bundles/wordpress/bundle/view/head:/bundles.yaml

`amqp` is the relation name, it communicates using the `rabbitmq` interface in `nova-cloud-controller` see the metadata.yaml file here:

- http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~charmers/charms/precise/nova-cloud-controller/trunk/view/head:/metadata.yaml

See this for a detailed description on relations and interfaces:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/authors-relations